# Challenge result deletes cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to do authorization over external service like google for example. For this purpose I return Challenge result with provider name. But the issue is that I don't fully understand this step. And I need to save current user's cookie. But Challenge replace current cookie identity with new external login identity. So how can I save cookie?

Comment: Did you see [Google external login setup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins)?  If so, include your configuration code.

Comment: @MarkG, Yeah, I saw. But I don't use asp identity and didn't understand how it can help me